# Fourth Corner Algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, function, matrix, package

This is a question about the fourthcorner algorithm in R.  It's designed to measure the relationship between three different tables: an n x m table (table R) of m environmental variables (columns) at n sites (rows), an n x p table (table L) of p abundances (columns) at n sites (rows), and a p x s table (table Q) of s traits (columns) for p species (rows).

The `fourthcorner` function is in the package `ade4`.

All three of my dataframes are binary (0s and 1s denoting the presence or absence of a variable, a species at a site, or a trait, respectively).  I've tried using "yes" and "no" instead of 0s and 1s without success.

Here are some example matrices in the format I'm using:

**tabQ**

```
Trait1  Trait2  Trait3  Trait4
Sp1 0   1   0   0
Sp2 0   1   0   0
Sp3 1   0   1   0
Sp4 1   0   1   0
Sp5 0   1   0   0
Sp6 0   1   0   0
Sp7 0   0   0   1
Sp8 0   0   0   1
```

**tabR**

```
EnV1    EnV2    EnV3    EnV4
Site1   1   1   1   1
Site2   1   1   0   1
Site3   0   1   0   1
Site4   1   1   1   1
Site5   1   1   0   1
Site6   0   1   0   0
Site7   0   1   0   1
Site8   0   1   0   1
Site9   1   1   1   1
Site10  1   1   0   1
Site11  1   1   1   1
Site12  0   1   0   0
Site13  1   1   0   1
Site14  1   1   0   1
Site15  0   1   0   1
Site16  1   1   0   1
Site17  0   1   0   1
Site18  1   1   1   1
Site19  1   1   0   1
Site20  1   1   0   1
```

**tabL**

```
Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6 Sp7 Sp8
Site1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site3   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
Site5   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site6   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Site7   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site8   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Site9   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site10  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site11  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
Site12  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
Site13  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site14  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Site15  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site16  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site17  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site18  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
Site19  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Site20  1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I read these dataframes into R from text files, and I specify that the first column is row names.

This is the error I get when I try to use the `fourthcorner` function on my matrices:

> fourth1=fourthcorner(tabR,tabL,tabQ,nrepet=1)
>
> Error in apply(sim, 2, function(x) length(na.omit(x))) : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length

I don't understand where the problem lies, is it a formatting issue? If so, should I reformat one of the matrices? Which one is causing the trouble? Or can I not use binary traits and environmental variables for this function?  In other words, can I solve this problem by changing a piece of code, or is it impossible to use this function for this question?

As an additional tidbit of information, I did email the author of the function, but unfortunately I did not understand his response fully, possibly because my R skills still leave much to be desired.  Here is his response if it is helpful:

> Q could contain quantitative or qualitative traits. In R, qualitative traits should be coded as factors to obtain adapted statistics (i.e. chi2 or eta2). If you code qualitative variables as dummy variables, they would be considered as quantitative.

Thank you very much to any and all insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that your example fails only `nrepet` is equal to one, so if you can use any other positive number you should be fine.

However, if you do need `nrepet=1`, you should contact with the author of `ade4` and ask to him/her to fix the `fourthcorner` function code. I traced back the error and found that `fourthcorner` calls `as.krandtest` with `sim = res$tabD[-1,]` where `res$tabD` is a matrix with `nrepet+1` rows. When `nrepet`=1 and you remove one row from a two-row matrix, `R` automatically converts the resulting one-row matrix into a vector, but `as.krandtest` function expects `sim` to be a matrix and thus raises the error.

Here is your input data just in case somebody else would like to answer your question:

**tabR**

```
structure(list(EnV1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), EnV2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), EnV3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), EnV4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("EnV1", 
"EnV2", "EnV3", "EnV4"), row.names = c("Site1", "Site2", "Site3", 
"Site4", "Site5", "Site6", "Site7", "Site8", "Site9", "Site10", 
"Site11", "Site12", "Site13", "Site14", "Site15", "Site16", "Site17", 
"Site18", "Site19", "Site20"), class = "data.frame")
```

**tabL**

```
structure(list(Sp1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Sp2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), Sp3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Sp4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sp5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Sp6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Sp7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Sp8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5", "Sp6", 
"Sp7", "Sp8"), row.names = c("Site1", "Site2", "Site3", "Site4", 
"Site5", "Site6", "Site7", "Site8", "Site9", "Site10", "Site11", 
"Site12", "Site13", "Site14", "Site15", "Site16", "Site17", "Site18", 
"Site19", "Site20"), class = "data.frame")
```

**tabQ**

```
structure(list(Trait1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Trait2 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Trait3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), Trait4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Trait1", 
"Trait2", "Trait3", "Trait4"), row.names = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", 
"Sp4", "Sp5", "Sp6", "Sp7", "Sp8"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow, I thought it might be something silly like that. I never thought it would be the number of repetitions though.  I only had it on a low number so that I could debug without the simulations running for hours.  This did work, thank you.